# Automatically collect and output all C++ dependencies

Tags: c++, makefile, g++

**Problem**

I need my code to compile on a machine that cannot leverage `apt-get` to install nonstandard C++ libraries but my C++ program has a single `#include` for an external library that I must use. That library includes many headers and other libraries, meaning that my `makefile` has many `-l` and `-I` to `/usr/include/...` and `/usr/lib/...` pointing to my `apt-get` installed libraries.

**What I want**

Rather than manually going through and grabbing all of these libraries so that I can include them in my project directory, I am hoping there is a command or flag for make or g++ that will dump all the libraries and headers into a directory for me.

**Progress**

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23739064/how-to-collect-all-dependencies-of-a-large-makefile-project) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204823/automatically-discovering-c-dependencies) have helped because adding the `-MMD` flag to my g++ compile command will dump out a list of about 100 header file locations. But I would like g++ to go one step further and actually do the work of gathering them all together for me, if that feature exists.

Comment: Some libraries have `my-lib-config` where you pass `--lib` or `--include` to have the required gcc flags.

Comment: @Jarod42 true but that doesn't grab all the files and output them to a directory for you.

Comment: Gathering the header files sounds straightforward, but I don't see a way to identify the libraries automatically.

Comment: @Beta I was worried about that. I noticed the `-MM` flag did not help with the libraries. So as far as you know, is my only option to `grep` or `find` the libraries and manually grab each one?

Comment: Grabbing all libraries in a directory tree automatically is straightforward. Identifying the libraries that are actually necessary... You might be able to parse the makefile, extract the `-l` flags, but Make would have to delegate that job to something like a Perl script.